# Sharing database between android and windows phone

Tags: java, android, database, windows-phone

I have application developed by different apk/api, I have version java Desktop application and Android Application and Windows phone 8.1 Application , My problem that the three version use the same database to access it can modify and insert ..etc
how i create shared database between them to use the same database via internet because i enforce my user to access the internet to use the application. There is any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Host a WebService for sharing data amongst devices. Using a simple php script to insert and select will allow you to achieve this.

Something like [this blog](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json) would help develop understanding of web services if you want a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a an online database without having to implement your own backend using this website [Parse](http://www.parse.com) and implement platform specific code to read/write data for different platforms using their SDKs.